# How to restore cursor position after the document is reformatted?

Tags: vimscript, line-numbers

I'm reformatting an XML document with an external command from a vimscript function which accepts a range,  and I need the cursor to stay at the same line it was before the reformatting. When trying to save the current cursor line number with `line('.')` or `getpos('.')`, the line number is always '1' and restoring it makes no sense. Any idea? Here is the functionL

```
" formats the XML source
function s:DapsXmlFormat() range
  " save the current cursor position as a mark
  let winview = winsaveview()
  " check if the current buffer is valid
  if s:DapsValidateFile() == 0
    let indent_size = indent(a:firstline) / shiftwidth()
    let cmd = '!' . b:xmlformat_script . ' -f ' . b:xmlformat_conf
    silent execute(a:firstline.','.a:lastline.cmd)
    if a:firstline > 1 && a:lastline < line('$')
      " re-indent the visual block
      let repeat = repeat(">", indent_size)
      " a:lastline is probably not valid anymore after re-formatting, need
      " matchit's % to mark the vusual block correctly
      silent execute("normal lV%" . indent_size . ">")
    endif
  endif
  " go back to the saved cursor position
  call winrestview(winview)
endfunction
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `:h :func-range` says,

```
            When the [range] argument is added, the function is
            expected to take care of a range itself.  The range is
            passed as "a:firstline" and "a:lastline".  If [range]
            is excluded, ":{range}call" will call the function for
            each line in the range, with the cursor on the start
            of each line.  See |function-range-example|.
--->        The cursor is still moved to the first line of the
--->        range, as is the case with all Ex commands.
```

Hence, you must save the view *before* ranged function/command. For example,

```
command! -nargs=+ -complete=command Nomove call misc#nomove(<q-args>)
...
...
function! misc#nomove(cmd) abort
    let l:pos = winsaveview()
    try | return execute(a:cmd, '')
    finally
        call winrestview(l:pos)
    endtry
endfunction
...
...
:Nomove 10,20call Foobar(...)
```

The alternative is simply to jump back with "double backqoute" (which restores the cursor position but not other view parameters).

Comment: I set that on my computer and get: E481: No range allowed