# Vim substitution and keep cursor in place

Tags: substitute, cursor-movement

I have a mapping in my `.vimrc`.

It is the following:

```
nnoremap q; :call Add_comment_css()<CR>
```

And then I can run, say `10q;`

And then it will run 10 times.

But my problem is that the cursor always moves as well.

I want the cursor to stay in place.

I have tried all the solutions here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10468324/how-to-run-a-search-and-replace-command-without-cursor-moving-in-vim

None of them works on my computer. Don't know why.

I have also tried having a variable that iterates.
Then store that variable in a register on each iteration.
Then afterwards I could somehow go back if I could figure out how to travel by line numbers, relative to current line, using a variable or register.

But that's just a hack.

What I really want, is to not travel when I apply the substitution.

My function is the following:

```
function! Add_comment_css()
    " Add At Beginning.
    s/^/\/\*
endfunction
```

Does anybody know how to do that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to restore cursor position after the document is reformatted?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/37839/how-to-restore-cursor-position-after-the-document-is-reformatted)

Comment: I get error, E481: No range allowed

Comment: Note that the reason `10q;` works is that it becomes `:.,.+9call Add…()`, which calls the function once for each line in the range since the function is not declared to handle the range itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do:

```
function! Add_comment_css(range, line1, line2)
  let l:pos = winsaveview()

  " Add At Beginning.
  if a:range == 2
    let command = a:line1 ."," . a:line2 .'s/^/\/\*'
    " echo command
    execute command
  elseif a:range == 0
    s/^/\/\*
  endif

  call winrestview(l:pos)
endfunction

command! -range=% AddCommentCss call Add_comment_css(<range>, <line1>, <line2>)
nnoremap q; :AddCommentCss<CR>
```

An alternative using pure function:

```
function! Add_comment_css() range
  let l:pos = winsaveview()

  " Add At Beginning.
  let command = a:firstline ."," . a:lastline .'s/^/\/\*'
  execute command

  call winrestview(l:pos)
endfunction

nnoremap q; :call Add_comment_css()<CR>
```

Comment: Now all the substitutions happen on the same, first line.

Comment: I updated the question, now it contains the function itself. Which always runs on the same line, as is.

Comment: I would not use `mkview` for this; IIRC it creates a file on disk. `winsaveview` &co. (or whatever it's called) should be sufficient.

Comment: And how would you use winsaveview?

Comment: Typically as in https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/37842/10604

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have inserted into the answer. I tested it and it seems to work like a charm :-)

Comment: No need for a big if operator...

Comment: I coped that onto my computer and I still get: E481: No range allowed. No idea why.

Comment: @Matt, Without the `if` if no count is inserted the entire file is commented.

Comment: It works for me ;-) Did you restarted Vim? What is your Vim version?

Comment: I finally managed to get it to work. thanks a lot guys.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback :-)

Comment: I was on the verge of becoming super depressed over this. but now its 17 o'clock and I just got that thing to work as im finishing the workday. So tmrw I can move it forward so I'm allright.

Comment: Why is there a line1 and line2?

Comment: Where does if a:range == 2 come from? What does it mean?

Comment: When you use a `-range` command you have three parameters populated `<range>`, `<line1>`, `<line2>`. `<range>` can be 0, 1 or 2. 0 if no range has been specified. 1 if it has been called `:3command`. 2 if a full range has been used `:3:5command`.

Comment: `<line1>` is the start value of the range, `<line2>` is the end value of the range.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142755/discussion-between-john-jones-and-vivian-de-smedt).

Answer (score 3):

First, it is important to understand *why* the substitution is applied on `[count]` lines when you do `[count]q;`.

`10q;` doesn't execute `q;` 10 times. It prepends `10` to the stream of inputs taken from the right-hand-side of  your `q;` mapping. In some cases it might behave like if you repeated your mapping 10 times:

```
nnoremap <key> dd
10<key>              " same as 10dd
```

but, in your case, `10` is prepended to `:call` and, as explained under `:help N:`, a count before `:` is automatically transformed into a range. But you are not done yet, `:help :call` has this to say about `[count]`:

```
[…]
When a range is given and the function doesn't handle it
itself, the function is executed for each line in the range,
with the cursor in the first column of that line.  The cursor
is left at the last line (possibly moved by the last function
call).  The arguments are re-evaluated for each line.
[…]
```

So this is your chain of transformations:

```
10q;
10:call Add_comment_css()<CR>
:.,.+9call Add_comment_css()<CR>
```

which explains why you end up calling that function on 10 lines.

From there, the next thing to decide is what meaning you want to give to `10` in `10q;`:

- Do you want it to express the number of lines you want to cover (current behavior)?
- Do you want it to be ignored?
- Do you want it to express the number of leading comments you add to the line?

If you want `[count]` to be ignored, then you should probably avoid giving a count to begin with. That's extra work that you want to have no effect so why bother?

If the count is accidental (it happens), then you could simply use the old `:help c_ctrl-u` technique:

```
nnoremap q; :<C-u>call Add_comment_css()<CR>
```

where `<C-u>` removes any accidental range before `call…`, or its more modern `:help <Cmd>` alternative:

```
nnoremap q; <Cmd>call Add_comment_css()<CR>
```

If you want `[count]` to express the number of leading comments you add to the line, then you will have to disable its native implicit handling first, then handle it explicitly:

```
function! Add_comment_css()
    for i in range(v:count1)
        silent s/^/\/\*
    endfor
endfunction
nnoremap q; <Cmd>call Add_comment_css()<CR>
```

If you are still using an older Vim without `<Cmd>`, use this mapping instead:

```
nnoremap q; :<C-u>call Add_comment_css()<CR>
```

See `:help :for`, `:help range()`, and `:help v:count1`.

Comment: Thanks Romain. Very interesting :-)

Comment: What concepts are you struggling with? The snippet at the bottom is tested and working in Vim 9.

Comment: If I copy the bottom paragraph into my code, nothing works if I have the <Cmd>. But if i have : instead of it. Then if I do 3q; it implements everything 3 times for the next 3 lines. So it's either nothing or 3 squared. I can fix it by removing the for i in range. but the cursor is always moving with the operation. I have tried fixing that by adding the winsaveview above and below as in the other example but it doesn't work. So I'm not able to get this to work.

Comment: I'm using Vim 8.1. Do you think that's the problem? I am trying to update to 9.x. apt update and upgrade doesn't work. I am trying to see how it's done on miscellaneous places. Most of them seem to not work and some are warning the newest versions may be unstable. Do you have any recommendation as to how to go about upgrade to some stable 9.x?

Comment: It seems like Vim 9 is still cutting edge and still not available in the default repository on linux. https://itsfoss.com/install-latest-vim-ubuntu/  I would really like to just chill with upgrade until its in the default repository. But then this example doesn't work. And then I can't fix my problem.

Comment: 1. I've added an alternative mapping for you. 2. 8.1 is almost 5 years old, it's time to upgrade. 3. Ubuntu 22.10 has 9.0 and 22.04 had 8.2. so nothing is stopping you from upgrading.

Comment: I'm using Mint. I've already upgraded to the latest and its still not in the repository. When I use <C-u> instead of <Cmd>, I get them all in the same line.

Comment: Which is the intended result.

Comment: What I wanted, was if i say, 3q; to get the pattern over the next 3 lines.

Comment: Your function already does that.

Comment: No. I copied the function and calling again into my system just now to be sure. It applies the substitution to current line x times. Not once per line for the next x lines.

Comment: And if I skip the <C-u> and just use : I get the pattern, x times per line for the next x lines. It's either x2 or nothing.

Comment: *Your* function already does what you want.

Comment: In my function I am skipping the for i in range part. But when I skip that, the mouse cursor moves along with the replacement. How do I make it stay in place?

Comment: You don't. That's how Ex commands work: they leave you on the last line they touched. But you can make the cursor come back to its original position with a mark or with `winsaveview()` as in the accepted answer.

Comment: I have already tried that. I put the winsaveview before the command. and call winrestview after the command. The cursor is still always changing locations.

Comment: And if I completely use the other guys function, its either x2. using call. Cmd gives me nothing and <C-u> only implements it once in the given line.

Comment: No never mind. I think it's working now. Thank you very much for you help.

Comment: Gentle reminder: for long-winded conversations, move to [chat]

Comment: It all now works super well so it's now all awesome-o.